# How to stop counting position of list-view from bottom.?

Tags: android, listview

I have List-view with 16 items, all view create perfect when activity start. When activity start list-view start with position zero from top. all view remain as it is, when i am scrolling smooth. But My problem is When list view reached on its last position and try to pull it hard,then its start counting from bottom. It means it take 16th position as 0(zero).

I am updating my top-third view with text-view's text value on top-third view.When activity start its work perfect,but above i tell that when reached on last position or hard pull my list-view, it start create view from bottom and set value of top-third view in bottom third-view.

this is my adapter get-view code.

```
  @Override
 public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 { 

  sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("ua_animation", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCESS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  Holder holder = null;
  c = unlock_animation.b;  
      sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("u_anim", c).commit();
      b1 = sharedPreferences.getInt("u_anim", 0);
      sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("sto_time", sc  reen_time_out.pt).commit();

      i4 = sharedPreferences.getInt("ptm", 0);
      i2 = sharedPreferences.getInt("switch_key", 0);
      if(i2 == 1){  tgpref = true; }else { tgpref = false; }

  LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //convertView = null;

    if(convertView == null){

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.screenlock_adapter, parent,false);

        holder = new Holder();      
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hsw = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_sw);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);        
        convertView.setTag(holder);               
    } else{                     
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }      


    if(position == 0){

    holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);        
    holder.hdesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);    

    }
    if(position == 1){            

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);            
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
        //holder.himg.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        holder.hsw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // do something, the isChecked will be
                // true if the switch is in the On position
                 if(isChecked ){

                    posi = 1; 
                    s.setValues(1);

                    }else{
                        posi = 0;
                        s.setValues(0);

                    }
            }
        });
        if(tgpref){
            holder.hsw.setChecked(true);

        }else
        {
            holder.hsw.setChecked(false);               
        }

    }
    if(position == 2){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        i1 = sharedPreferences.getInt("value", 0);
        switch(i1){

        case 1:
            holder.hdesc.setText("shake");
            break;
        case 2:
            holder.hdesc.setText("single tap");
            break;
        case 3:
            holder.hdesc.setText("Double tap");
            break;
        }

    }
    if(position == 3){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.himg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    if(position == 4){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        //holder.himg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.hsw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked ){

                 vibratorv = 1;
                    v.setValue(1);

                    }else{
                    vibratorv = 0;
                        v.setValue(0);
                    }
                }
        });
        if(vbool){
            holder.hsw.setChecked(true);                
        }else{
            holder.hsw.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    if(position == 5){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.hdesc.setText(R.string.desc);

    }
    if(position == 6){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);  
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.hdesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if(i5 == 0){holder.hdesc.setText("Default");}
        if(i5 == 1){holder.hdesc.setText("0s");}
        if(i5 == 2){holder.hdesc.setText("3s");}
        if(i5 == 3){holder.hdesc.setText("5s");}
        if(i5 == 4){holder.hdesc.setText("15s");}
        if(i5 == 5){holder.hdesc.setText("30s");}
        if(i5 == 6){holder.hdesc.setText("1m");}

    }
    if(position == 7){

        Toast.makeText(context, "i4 : "+i4, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);           
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        if(i4 == 0){holder. hdesc.setText("Default");}
        if(i4 == 1){holder.hdesc.setText("0s");}
        if(i4 == 2){holder.hdesc.setText("3s");}
        if(i4 == 3){holder.hdesc.setText("5s");}
        if(i4 == 4){holder.hdesc.setText("15s");}
        if(i4 == 5){holder.hdesc.setText("30s");}
        if(i4 == 6){holder.hdesc.setText("1m");}

    }

    if(position == 8){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
        switch(b1){

        case 0:
            holder.hdesc.setText("None");       
            break;
        case 1:
            holder.hdesc.setText("Rotate");
            break;
        case 2:
            holder.hdesc.setText("Fade");
            break;
        case 3:
            holder.hdesc.setText("Zoom");
            break;
        case 4:
            holder.hdesc.setText("Bounce");
            break;
        case 5:
            holder.hdesc.setText("Blink");
            break;
        }

    }
    if(position == 9){
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.hdesc.setText(R.string.desc);


    }
    if(position == 10){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        //holder.himg.setVisibility(View.GONE);         
        holder.hdesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        holder.hsw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked ){

                 //sb = "1";
                    sb.setstatusbar(1);

                    }else{
                   // sb = "0";
                        sb.setstatusbar(0);
                    }
                }
        });
        if(statusbool){
            holder.hsw.setChecked(true);                
        }else{
            holder.hsw.setChecked(false);
        }

    }
    if(position ==11){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.hdesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    }
    if(position == 12){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);         
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.hdesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    }
    if(position == 13){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);                 
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.hdesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    if(position == 14){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);         
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.hdesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    if(position == 15){

        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);         
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.dir_arrow).into(holder.himg);
        holder.hdesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.hsw.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    return convertView;

  }

 public void posi(){
     sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("ua_anim", unlock_animation.b).commit();
     bc = sharedpreferences.getInt("ua_anim", 0);
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you show a methods in your adapter: getCount()?  getItem(int position) and long getItemId(int position)...

Comment: `if(position == x)` in `getView` is almost always a bad idea ... also you are not "reseting" the views for all cases ... do you know how recycling works in the ListView? no ? then there is [a time to fix it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: @selvin     This is my get count method.                                              public int getCount()
  {
    return Listitem.length;
  }

Comment: *not "reseting" the views for all cases* ... fx in `if(position == 2) {}` you never touch `holder.hdesc` visibility ... now add recycling into that ...

Comment: I am recycling this view from activity using method. @Selvin

Comment: This third View recycled when I receive data from second activity. @Selvin

Comment: FSM save us! you copy&pasted some code without understanding ... you have no idea what recycling means just using view holder pattern without thinking ... take a look at the link from my first comment ...

Comment: also getView is called **only** when new item appear **not for every visible items** (of course if you do not invalidate whole adapter) ... so when you are scrolling it may only change first or last item ... rest stay the same .... also position means position of data not position on the screen

Comment: i am using this method to refresh my listview's row.                                                `private void updateItemAtPosition(int position) {
    int visiblePosition = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View view = list.getChildAt(position - visiblePosition);
    list.getAdapter().getView(position, view, list);
}` , is this wrong.? then tell me.  @Selvin

Comment: *is this wrong.?* for me? FUBAR - f* up beyond all repair ....

Comment: what is solution for this.? how can i update whole adapter, i dont want to use `recreate()` or restart activity. Any other solution then welcome. @Selvin

Comment: @Selvin i have find the  solution for my issue, I have posted as answer. You can see that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got my questions solution. i have convert-view to constant value null `convertview = null;`  and from activity, I am updating my list-view adapter using this method.

```
private void updateData() {

  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
              ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
  });
}
```

Calling this method when i receive data from other activity.